# Is there a way to map a field with automapper if the source field needs to be counted by a given condition?

Tags: c#, automapper

I basically want to count the source field by a given condition. The plan is to count the navigation properties number (1 request can have multiple safechecks, so Safechecks is a virtual ICollection in the design), but separate them by its own Checktype field's value, like so:

```
        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(
              cfg =>
              {
                  cfg.CreateMap<ListRequestsViewModel, Requests>().ReverseMap()
                 .ForMember(d => d.Nr_Sum_SafeChecks, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SafeChecks.Count))
                 .ForMember(d => d.Nr_Quality_SafeChecks, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SafeChecks.Where(x => x.CheckType.Equals("Qlty")).Count)) 
                 .ForMember(d => d.Nr_Quantity_SafeChecks, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SafeChecks.Where(x => x.CheckType.Equals("Qnty").Count));

              }
            );
```

The first "ForMember" row is legal, in case of the other two (Nr_Quality_SafeChecks and Nr_Quantity_SafeChecks), I got "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IValueResolver<Requests, ListRequestsViewModel, object>' because it is not a delegate type" error. So this is not working as it is.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Have that lamba call a separate helper method that takes the source object. That way it will be easier to diagnose errors and you can reuse the code for Qlty adn Qnty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IEnumerable.Count()`.

```
.ForMember(d => d.Nr_Quality_SafeChecks, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SafeChecks.Count(x => x.CheckType.Equals("Qlty"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

s.SafeChecks.Where(...) clause returns an IEnumerable where .Count not supported. However, it can be called on an ICollection like List, so converting to list first should solve the problem.

```
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(
          cfg =>
          {
              cfg.CreateMap<ListRequestsViewModel, Requests>().ReverseMap()
             .ForMember(d => d.Nr_Sum_SafeChecks, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SafeChecks.Count))
             .ForMember(d => d.Nr_Quality_SafeChecks, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SafeChecks.Where(x => x.CheckType.Equals("Qlty")).ToList().Count)) 
             .ForMember(d => d.Nr_Quantity_SafeChecks, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SafeChecks.Where(x => x.CheckType.Equals("Qnty")).ToList().Count));

          }
        );
```

Comment: `MapFrom(s => s.SafeChecks.Count(x => x.CheckType.Equals("Qlty"))` Shorter and way more efficient :)

Comment: You are right, thanks. If you could post it as an answer, I would accept that.